# How to Autowire business objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc

I'm following the Controller -> Service -> DAO pattern. When I call a DAO implementation, I get back a DTO/Data object. Which then gets passed to the service layer, bringing together it's respective business object and it's data object. Like so:

```
public User getUserById(int id) {
    return new User(userDAO.getUserById(id));
}

class User {
    private UserDTO userDTO;

    public User(UserDTO userDTO) {
        this.userDTO = userDTO;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is wrap ALL my business logic inside the business class but I require additional dependencies.
For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
//... some code

User user = userService.getByUserId(1);

user.delete(); // this should delete the user from the database
```

In order for me to delete the user this way, I would need to Autowire the UserService into the business class but this will not work since I am manually instantiating the User class in the User Service.

```
class User {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; // this won't work since I call instantiate User myself, ie. new User()
    private UserDTO userDTO;

    public User(UserDTO userDTO) {
        this.userDTO = userDTO;
    }

    public boolean delete() {
        userService.deleteByUserId(userDTO.getId());
    }
}
```

Is there a pattern I can follow to allow me to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good design to have business class as a member of your DTO objects.
A more proper approach would be to have your delete method in the business class. That would help loose coupling.

Comment: The delete is in the business class.

Comment: So why do you want to call it from user object ? just call userService.deleteUser(user) where you need it

Comment: As the code becomes more complex, I require the functionality to be duplicated in multiple places. I'd like to reuse the same delete logic everywhere. I can't place all the of the delete logic in the service class because then it will not be too reusable.

Comment: So again, you are violating another very important programming principle: DRY (Don't repeat your self). In what case duplicating code would be more helpful then just calling userService.delete(user) !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with the `@Configurable` annotation, though this really isn't how Spring is supposed to work. It will add lots of overhead to your application and make debugging harder.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable